# jQuery Mobile select align left

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile in a form and all of my selects have options which are aligned center. I have tried numerous things like:

```
.ui-select {
  text-align:left !important;
}

select {
  text-align:left !important;
}

option {
  text-align:left !important;
}
```

but the text keeps having an alignment of center. Is it possible to change this?

Comment: could you show html as you define a form?

Comment: Basic html tags I guess: <select id="klid"><option value="">Selecteer klant</option></select>. When using * { text-align:left !important; } everything does move left.

Comment: '...everything does move left' - is that you wish?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!

jQuery Mobile inserts a  tag to show which option has been selected. This element has text-align:center by default. By changing the CSS, it now shows correctly.

Comment: Found it and works. The tag is a `span` tag. `.ui-select span`